# Is "according to plan" correct?

Tags: articles

I saw many people's writing containing this phrase, but I am wondering why it does not need an article before the plan.

Comment: I think the lack of a determiner / article in *Everything's going **according to [the/a] plan*** is similar to *The organisation is **not fit for [the/its] purpose***. Effectively they're both "clipped, business-speak" set phrases, thsat shouldn't be taken as a guide to syntax in other contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an article before "plan" because this is a well established common phrase. It's a unit of speech on its own.

If you were to use these words in a more complex sentence, you will need proper grammar.

*The games were structured according to the plan agreed during the last meeting.*